# query an empty string in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Is that possible that try to query an empty string in elasticsearch without error?
The situation now in my case is there are some words is stored in index, I will receive some data, I want use this kind of data as query data. I can not control the data, so sometimes the data  could be empty string. 
E.g.

```
query={"query":{"query_stirng":{"query":""}}}

Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse '   ': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 3.
Was expecting one of:
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    <TERM> ...
    "*" ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:213)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 3.
Was expecting one of:
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <NUMBER> ...
    <TERM> ...
    "*" ...

    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:708)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:590)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:275)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:181)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:121)
    ... 16 more
```

Is that possible to use elasticsearch to solve this problem or must use code the solve this? **So that I can receive the empty data and query with elasticsearch and elasitcsearch will not cause any problem?**

Environment :
Ubuntu 12.04 desktop 64bit

elasticsearch 0.90.7 >> single node

programming language: python

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the missing filter will work in this case:

[Missing Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "user",
          "existence": true,
          "null_value": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OP ain't asking about missing fields. OP is asking about empty query search.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its not possible as of now. You need to handle it in the code with some try-catch mechanism (Exception handling).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with String fields containing empty string values. Using Query DSL, I managed to get empty strings by using: (if document contains "field" : "" )

```
 "query": {
       "query_string": {
          "query": "( _exists_:field && -field:* )"                 
       }
   }
```

this basically means, "field is not null, and it is not any string".

similarly, excluding empty strings would be:

```
   "query": {
       "query_string": {
          "query": "( _missing_:field || field:* )"                 
       }
   }
```

which means "field is null OR any string".